# Wrong offset(); on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `offset();` to set the position of a `.nav` menu on bootstrap and make `fixed` when the `scroll intersection` the `.r-logo-menu-desktop` class, near the .nav menu, adding a `fixed` class to `.nav` and remove it when the scroll goes to top and let the `.nav` in the same `position`. In Safari/Chrome work's fine but in Firefox the menu goes `fixed` too son, in the middle of the slider, instead in the end. You can see the example [here](https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/habitaciones.html).

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav"><nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg mx-auto navbar-dark bg-white">       

    <div class="mx-auto order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
                 <img class="r-logo-menu" src="img/Logos-RUCAB-7.png" />
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-2">
        <ul  class="navbar-nav mx-auto mr-auto text-center">
         <img class="r-logo-menu-desktop" src="img/Logos-RUCAB-7.png" />
        <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#home"><span data-hover="HOME">HOME</span></a>
            </li>
                    </nav>
                  <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#rucab"><span data-hover="RUCAB">RUCAB</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
                    <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#inscripciones"><span data-hover="INSCRIPCIONES">INSCRIPCIONES</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
             <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#habitaciones"><span data-hover="HABITACIONES">HABITACIONES</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
              <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#staff"><span data-hover="STAFF">STAFF</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
             <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact"><span data-hover="BLOG">BLOG</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>
                    <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="#contacto"><span data-hover="CONTACTO">CONTACTO</span></a>
            </li>
             </nav>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
      // cache the element
var $navBar = $('.nav');
    var $rlogo = $('.r-logo-menu-desktop');

// find original navigation bar position
var navPos = $navBar.offset().top;

// on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // get scroll position from top of the page
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    // check if scroll position is >= the nav position
    if (scrollPos >= navPos) {
        $navBar.addClass('fixed');
        $rlogo.addClass('show');
    } else {
        $navBar.removeClass('fixed');
        $rlogo.removeClass('show');
    }

});
```

CSS

```
.r-logo-menu-desktop.show {

    margin-bottom: 2px;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    width: 60px;
    margin-right: 20px;

}

.r-logo-menu-desktop {
opacity: 0; 
margin-right: 20px;  
transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    height: 90px;
    background: #fff;
}

.nav-wrapper .nav {
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar-nav {
    background: #fff;
}

.nav-wrapper .nav.fixed {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

UPDATED SCRIPT:

```
var $header = $('#carouselExampleIndicators');
var $navBar = $('.nav');
var $rlogo = $('.r-logo-menu-desktop');

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var headerPos = $header.height();
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos >= headerPos)
    {
        $navBar.addClass('fixed');
        $rlogo.addClass('show');
    }
    else
    {
        $navBar.removeClass('fixed');
        $rlogo.removeClass('show');
    }

});
```

Comment: This is not correct how i see in firefox / Edge? https://imgur.com/a/I7BKVOG

Comment: PS: The problem is not for Firefox. I found this in Chrome :)

Comment: The code works fine for my. but put the id: #carouselExampleIndicators-custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Try like this. Because the header is changing the height, you need to get that for position.

```js
var $header = $('#carouselExampleIndicators-custom');
var $navBar = $('.nav');
var $rlogo = $('.r-logo-menu-desktop');

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var headerPos = $header.height();
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos >= headerPos)
    {
        $navBar.addClass('fixed');
        $rlogo.addClass('show');
    }
    else
    {
        $navBar.removeClass('fixed');
        $rlogo.removeClass('show');
    }

});
```

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0}
body{font-size:0;height:1920px}
img{width:100%}
.r-logo-menu-desktop{visibility:hidden}
.r-logo-menu-desktop.show{visibility:unset}
#carouselExampleIndicators-custom{display:block;background:#a3b0b0}
.nav{display:block;background:#cad7d7;padding:8px}
.nav.fixed{position:fixed;width:100%;top:0}
ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;font-family:Arial;font-size:24px}
ul li{display:inline}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="carouselExampleIndicators-custom"><img src="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/1400_slider1.jpg"></header>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><span class="r-logo-menu-desktop">R</span></li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it  (the first code block) and nearly worked, it's attached correctly on Firefox when the offset intersection the nav. The problem is when I scroll to the top, the menu didn't revert to the original position, it's get stacked to the top of the window forever.

Comment: Yeah but you need to set a static height on the body, like 1920px, is there any way to avoid it? And set the height to auto. Because... if the height have more than 1920px, what happen?

Comment: Yeah but you need to set a static height on the body, like 1920px, is there any way to avoid it? And set the height to auto. Because... if the height have more than 1920px, what happen?

Comment: I put the height because i don't have content to show the scroll. Try only the JQuery code if works.

Comment: Your code with the class and id's didn't work, I used the code that you can see in the answer updated and it worked, I don't know if It can be a valid solution, can u check it? Thanks.