# Scroll-linked positioning doesn't work if I scroll too fast. Is there a better method?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I'm trying to make a header that has a margin on the top, left, and right until being scrolled, at which point it should smoothly grow until there is no longer any margin.

I've taken care of the margin-top with 'position: sticky' and have tried using scroll-linked positioning to progressively grow the header horizontally.

HTML

```
<header id = "header">
  <h1>Hi there</h1>
</header>
```

JS

```
  window.onscroll = function() { /* wait until page loaded */
     var margin = 15;
     var borderOffset = 1.875; /* 15/8 */
    var scrollStatus = window.pageYOffset;
    var header = document.getElementById("header");

    if (scrollStatus <= margin) {
      header.style.marginLeft = (margin - scrollStatus) + "px";
      header.style.marginRight = (margin - scrollStatus) + "px";
      header.style.borderRadius = ((margin - scrollStatus) / borderOffset) + "px";
    }
  };
```

CSS

```
header {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yryZBb

However, when I scroll the page too fast, the header doesn't completely grow. How can I make this work?

Comment: I make another post on this link: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55446665/6168288) Try that.

Answer (score 1):

If you not want JQuery:

```js
let header = document.getElementById("header");
let nav = document.getElementById("nav");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function ()
{
    let marginTop = 10;

    if (window.scrollY >= (header.clientHeight + marginTop))
    {
        nav.style.position = "fixed";
        nav.style.width = "100%";
        nav.style.margin = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        nav.style.position = "";
        nav.style.width = "";
        nav.style.margin = "";
    }
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { height: 1200px; }
img { width: 100%; }

#header { background: #a3b0b0; }
#nav { background: #cad7d7; padding: 8px; top: 0; margin: 10px 40px; }

ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
ul li { display: inline; }
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <img src="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/1400_slider1.jpg">
</header>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just added

```
  else {
  header.style.marginLeft = "0";
  header.style.marginRight = "0";
  header.style.borderRadius = "0";
}
```

right after `if (scrollStatus <= margin) {...}` to make sure the header grows completely. Probably not the best way to do this, so I won't mark this as accepted just yet.